# Residential buildings stuck at 0/0

Tags: cities-skylines

I am playing Cities skylines and building a city but now that I am expanding, buildings are stuck at 0/0 households. Why is that? They are connected to highways and have electricity and water.

The buildings are being built but no one moves in and my population is stuck at 48k.

Comment: What does your RCI look like?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess it that you reached the limit of what your computer can handle. I have an old computer with only 4gb of ram and I'm also stuck at about 40k people. Every city builder has a limit and when you reach it, things start to stop functioning.